# Magento - Add array of SKU's to shopping cart

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7

I'm working on a add product by sku form for a e-commerce website I'm developing.
I made the form which basically has 2 fields, "cod" and "qt".

I've passed that to this script (edited):

```
<?php
    $sku = $_POST['cod'];
    $qty = $_POST['qt'];
    $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

    $osids = array();

    foreach ($sku as $lol){
        $lolz = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$lol)->getId();
        array_push($osids, $lolz);

    }
var_dump($osids);

$params = array(
    'qty' => 2,
);
$cart->addProductsByIds($osids, $params);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);


?>
```

The var_dump displays the array correctly, ie. multiple skus when that's the case, but the foreach loop only adds the first sku in the array to the shopping cart.

Any idea why?

I wan't it to add all the sku's in the array.

Comment: I would suggest you to add the product by url it would be easy and u dont have write any code just have to pass the sku and quantity by querystring and magento would do the rest

Comment: That would be fine for one SKU, but it doesn't work for multiple SKU's does it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
<?php
    $sku_list = $_POST['cod'];
    $qty = $_POST['qt'];
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

    foreach ($sku_list as $sku){
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
        $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
    }
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. No product was added to the cart this time.
The way I see it, you initialized the cart before the foreach loop and saved it when it ended, which makes sense, so I can't see why it isn't working.

Comment: Maybe try your luck with $cart->addProductsByIds() and pass in an array of all product IDs?

Comment: Great, it works! Now I need to pass the quantities too though, does the addProductsByIds() function accept parameters? If so, how? Can't find documentation about it.

Comment: I made a change to my original code, if you take a look at the Cart Model, app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php you can see both functions and the parameters. In the case of the addProduct() function it takes 2 parameters $productInfo and $requestInfo, in your case you only need to pass the product object($product) as the $product info and the quantity($qty) as the request info. That should do the trick, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the above code, helped me make a start on an auto add additional products model that I need to write